text label is not showing on rectangle
Code
#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_color1 Blue



//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
    // Indicator buffer
   
    return INIT_SUCCEEDED; // Return success
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                                |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
{
   
   // Define the time and price for the rectangle
    datetime startTime = Time[10];  // Start time for the rectangle
    datetime endTime = Time[0];      // End time for the rectangle
    double topPrice = High[10];       // Top price for the rectangle
    double bottomPrice = Low[0];     // Bottom price for the rectangle
   
    // Create a rectangle
    string rectName = "MyRectangle";
    ObjectCreate(rectName, OBJ_RECTANGLE, 0, startTime, topPrice, endTime, bottomPrice);

        // Set properties for the rectangle
        ObjectSetInteger(0, rectName, OBJPROP_COLOR, clrBlue);
        ObjectSetInteger(0, rectName, OBJPROP_STYLE, STYLE_SOLID);
        ObjectSetInteger(0, rectName, OBJPROP_WIDTH, 2);
 

    
    // Create a text label for the rectangle name
    string labelName = "RectangleLabel";
    double labelY = topPrice; // Position label at the top of the rectangle
    ObjectCreate(labelName, OBJ_LABEL, 0, startTime, labelY);
    
        // Set properties for the label
        ObjectSetString(0, labelName, OBJPROP_TEXT, rectName);
        ObjectSetInteger(0, labelName, OBJPROP_COLOR, clrWhite);
        ObjectSetInteger(0, labelName, OBJPROP_FONTSIZE, 12);
        ObjectSetInteger(0, labelName, OBJPROP_XSIZE, 0); // Prevents shifting with size change
        ObjectSetInteger(0, labelName, OBJPROP_YSIZE, 0);
        // Adjust position slightly for visibility
        ObjectSetInteger(0, labelName, OBJPROP_YDISTANCE, 5); // Move text slightly below the top
   

}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

text label is not showing on rectangle. Could you help me to adjust code?

The text label is not showing on the rectangle because I am using OBJ_LABEL, which positions text relative to the chart window (not within the chart's price-time coordinates). To make the label appear at a specific position within the chart (aligned with the rectangle), I should use OBJ_TEXT instead of OBJ_LABEL.
